# What is a perfect motherboard for my budget build I3 8100 + GTX 1050 TI 4 GB?

Tags: motherboard

I find on Google about the motherboard for I3 8100 + GTX 1060 but it keep saying about Asus - Prime Z370-P ATX LGA1151 Motherboard, which is a near high-end motherboard at $120 for Intel Core I7 which is for my budget build, it is unacceptable. So any alternative solutions for this motherboard ?

Comment: Do you have any plans to upgrade to an unlocked CPU in the future?

Comment: I don’t want to overclock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Whatever's cheapest [here](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/#xcx=0&s=30&c=129,130,128&sort=price&m=7,8,14,27,94).

**Currently that's an [MSI B360M PRO-VD](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813144164&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=) for $55.99.**

[Since your CPU doesn't support overclocking](https://ark.intel.com/products/126688/Intel-Core-i3-8100-Processor-6M-Cache-3_60-GHz), unless you have plans to upgrade to an unlocked chip, getting a Z series board is unnecessary for overclocking. As such, [no motherboard will offer a performance boost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx8rS9_vNDo), assuming it supports your RAM speed, which–based on the tier of the rest of the system–I'm assuming isn't particularly high, and is likely supported by all motherboards.

From there I've basically just selected for price. You may be losing some I/O, and most of the cheaper boards only support 2 RAM modules (not a huge deal since your system only supports dual channel anyways, unless you have plans to upgrade your RAM), but it shouldn't really matter too much.

I've additionally chosen to eliminate Biostar and Gigabyte–not because their products are bad, but because of their relatively poor customer support.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend, 
[MSI H110M Gaming][1][1]: https://m.newegg.com/products/N82E16813130918

Since you are on a budget and the fact that your only using a 1050 ti this motherboard should just do the job, it only comes in at around $60.

Comment: It not what i asking for

Comment: You suck! How can you recommend something like that! It not for Coffe Lake! This motherboard don’t compatible with this motherboard! All Coffe Lake chips don’t compatible with older gen of motherboard!

Comment: It only compatible with the 300 series motherboard! I will downvote you if i can

Comment: Well sorry for giving advice, maybe I shouldn't have even commented.

Comment: Im kidding im just overreacting yesterday! Advice and learning is good dude! I just have bad thing to thinking so it make me overreacting! Im apperaciate what you has done!